# How can I extract multiple attributes of manager in AD using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a one line powershell command to extract managers from active directory, but it only gives me one attribute. What can I do to get more attributes like name, sAMAccountName and employeeNumber.

The command below just gives the employeeNumber of manager.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=Office365,DC=example,DC=lan" -Properties * | Select-Object name, employeeNumber, @{Name='Manager';Expression={(Get-ADUser -Property employeeNumber $_.Manager).employeeNumber}} | export-csv -path c:\temp\userexport.csv
```

Desired csv file headers:

```
name    employeeNumber   ManagerName      ManagerEmployeeNumber
```

Comment: You can retrieve multiple values and join them together with a delimiter. However, that particular *cell* in your CSV will now have a list of items.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you want the resulting CSV file to look?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Just updated the post with desired csv columns.

Answer (score 2):

If you are attempting to store multiple values in a *single cell* of a CSV file, you will have to create a delimited list within that cell.

```
# Calculated property joining property values with ;
# Use try-catch because some users may not have a manager
# No manager will throw a [ParameterBindingValidationException] exception.
$ManagerProp = @{
    Name='Manager'
    Expression={
        try {
            $user = Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties EmployeeNumber
            "{0};{1};{2}" -f $user.Name,$user.SamAccountName,$user.EmployeeNumber
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=Office365,DC=example,DC=lan" -Properties EmployeeNumber,Manager |
    Select-Object Name,EmployeeNumber,$ManagerProp |
        Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\userexport.csv -NoType
```

`-f` is the [String format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html).

Note that it is not efficient to use `-Properties *` because of the overhead required to retrieve unneeded properties.

---

You *could* give each `Manager` property its own property:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=Office365,DC=example,DC=lan" -Properties EmployeeNumber,Manager |
    Foreach-Object {
        $obj = [pscustomobject]@{
            Name = $_.Name
            EmployeeNumber = $_.EmployeeNumber
            Manager_Name = ''
            Manager_SamAccountName = ''
            Manager_EmployeeNumber = ''
        }
        if ($_.Manager) {
            $Manager = Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties EmployeeNumber
            $obj.Manager_Name = $Manager.Name
            $obj.Manager_SamAccountName = $Manager.SamAccountName
            $obj.Manager_EmployeeNumber = $Manager.EmployeeNumber
        }
        $obj
        }
    } | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\userexport.csv -NoType
```

Comment: Nice examples and explanation, this should be tagged as resolved.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation. I don't want to store the attributes in the same cell. I basically want 4 columns in my csv file - Name, EmployeeNumber, Manager Name, Manager EmployeeNumber. I am sorry, I am not a powershell expert, just trying to make best use of it.